# How to get data on the calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, sql-server

sample code is working well but i want to get data from db, how can do it?

**sample code;** (its working well)

```
       CalendarEvent item = new CalendarEvent();

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, random.Next(1, 30));

item.id = random.Next(1, 100);
            item.start = startDate.ToString("s");
            item.end = startDate.AddDays(random.Next(1, 5)).ToString("s");
item.allDay = true;
            item.color = "blue";
            item.title = "Calendar Item " + item.id;
            eventItems.Add(item);
```

**its my code;** (i cant any data from db with this my code, where is the problem?)

```
            sql.Add("Select * from Calendar Where StartDate>=@StartDate and EndDate<=@EndDate");
            sql.CmdType = CommandType.Text;
            sql.Prameter("@id", item.id);
            sql.Prameter("@Title", item.title.ToString());
            sql.Prameter("@StartDate", item.start);
            sql.Prameter("@EndDate", item.end);
            sql.Prameter("@Color", item.color);
            sql.Prameter("@AllDay", item.allDay);

            eventItems.Add(item);
```

Comment: `sql.Prameter`?

Comment: SQL Query: 
Select * From Calendar Where StartDate>=@StartDate and EndDate<=@EndDate

Comment: Did you test query in SQL Server Management Studio.  The error messages are much better in SSMS than c#.

Comment: there isnt any problem in sql query

Comment: What exactly does "get them on the calendar" mean? Does your query return the correct rows? Is this a problem with retrieving information from the database and displaying it in some fashion within your application? Something else?

Comment: Is `sql.Prameter` something disguising `AddWithValue`? If you're querying a calendar with @StartDate and @EndDate parameters then you're going to need to parse those values in as DateTime instances.

Comment: help me pls :( this return nulls

Comment: how can i cıbvert it datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `startDate` and `endDate` are converted to datetime format (match with the datatype of the `startDate` and `EndDate` on the Database). You can use your own connection method instead of `ConfigurationManager`

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.start);
DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.end);

string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["{yourConnectionKey}"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Calendar Where StartDate>=@StartDate and EndDate<=@EndDate", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //Seems your query are only requesting @startDate and @EndDate
        //You can add the other requested parameters as your needed.
        //eg. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.id); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         while (reader.Read())
         {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
            //action for the result data...
         }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

[Click here to get more reference from Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)